# Find a (16,6,1) Balanced incomplete block design (BIBD)

Tags: combinatorial-designs

I'm trying to find a balanced incomplete block design with the 16 items and $\lambda= 1$. I've calculated (using [these](https://www.google.nl/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=7&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CE8QFjAG&url=http://www.springer.com/cda/content/document/cda_downloaddocument/9780387954875-c1.pdf?SGWID=0-0-45-101851-p9775353&ei=QcFjU7KdJYWsPMKbgMAJ&usg=AFQjCNHOD_L5-yHLJ9kpg1DjOk8q0m1mTg&sig2=QBeGMwbIqn4-vA3-eHQy5w&bvm=bv.65788261,d.ZWU) defenitions)  that a BIBD with 8 blocks and 6 items per block should be possible. However, when trying to contruct this [with r](http://www.r-bloggers.com/generating-balanced-incomplete-block-designs-bibd/), it only finds not-balanced sets.

A balanced set with $\lambda=2$ (and 16 blocks) can be found for example, but as the goal is to let participants rank sets of items, the target is to keep the effort to a minimum.

My question: is such a BIBD possible, and if yes, how do I construct a valid one?

Thanks in advance,
Simon

Answer (score 0):

Such a design cannot exist for it will violate [Fisher's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher's_inequality).

Answer (score -1):

For those interested, it's not possible. The first possibility with 16,6 is a lambda of 2.

Comment: How didn't this answer the question? I asked whether it's possible, it's not. Seems like an answer to me :)